# Python Scrapy spider randomly stops going to next page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been trying to adapt this Scrapy spider I found on GitHub (see [here](https://github.com/ian-kerins/google-scholar-scrapy-spider)) but I'm getting bizarre behaviour: the scraper works and extracts several pages of Google Scholar results - as it should - but after a random number of pages it just quits out. It doesn't error or anything and it always successfully scrapes a few pages of results but then will just cease running (I'll get anything from 30 to maybe 250 individual Google Scholar entries).

For reference, the code is also [described in this blog post](https://dev.to/iankerins/build-your-own-google-scholar-api-with-python-scrapy-4p73), and relies on the API Scraper service to prevent the website blocking you.

The key code below (in the file scholar.py) is:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import json
from datetime import datetime

API_KEY = '<used my own key>'

def get_url(url):
    payload = {'api_key': API_KEY, 'url': url, 'country_code': 'us'}
    proxy_url = 'http://api.scraperapi.com/?' + urlencode(payload)
    return proxy_url


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scholar'
    allowed_domains = ['api.scraperapi.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        queries = ['airbnb']
        for query in queries:
            url = 'https://scholar.google.com/scholar?' + urlencode({'hl': 'en', 'q': query})
            yield scrapy.Request(get_url(url), callback=self.parse, meta={'position': 0})

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.url)
        position = response.meta['position']
        for res in response.xpath('//*[@data-rp]'):
            link = res.xpath('.//h3/a/@href').extract_first()
            temp = res.xpath('.//h3/a//text()').extract()
            if not temp:
                title = "[C] " + "".join(res.xpath('.//h3/span[@id]//text()').extract())
            else:
                title = "".join(temp)
            snippet = "".join(res.xpath('.//*[@class="gs_rs"]//text()').extract())
            cited = res.xpath('.//a[starts-with(text(),"Cited")]/text()').extract_first()
            temp = res.xpath('.//a[starts-with(text(),"Related")]/@href').extract_first()
            related = "https://scholar.google.com" + temp if temp else ""
            num_versions = res.xpath('.//a[contains(text(),"version")]/text()').extract_first()
            published_data = "".join(res.xpath('.//div[@class="gs_a"]//text()').extract())
            position += 1
            item = {'title': title, 'link': link, 'cited': cited, 'relatedLink': related, 'position': position,
                    'numOfVersions': num_versions, 'publishedData': published_data, 'snippet': snippet}
            yield item
        next_page = response.xpath('//td[@align="left"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            url = "https://scholar.google.com" + next_page
            yield scrapy.Request(get_url(url), callback=self.parse,meta={'position': position})
```

I played around with adding a few print statements to see what the issue was: when the code stops executing, it think it's finished. As far as I can tel in the 'for res in response.xpath('//*[@data-rp]'):' loop on an iteration it stops running it seems to think there's no data available to scrape - but that's not true as it'll stop on page 10 or 15 or whatever but there'll be thousands of pages left.

For reference I've put my Scrapy stats (output when it finishes) below - obviously these change slightly depending on how long the run has gone on for:

```
{'downloader/request_bytes': 8290,
 'downloader/request_count': 15,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 15,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 542659,
 'downloader/response_count': 15,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 15,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 65.051368,
 'feedexport/success_count/FileFeedStorage': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 18, 13, 0, 27, 256492),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 2064229,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 15,
 'item_scraped_count': 140,
 'log_count/INFO': 12,
 'memusage/max': 65363968,
 'memusage/startup': 52383744,
 'request_depth_max': 14,
 'response_received_count': 15,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 15,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 15,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 15,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 15,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 18, 12, 59, 22, 205124)}
```

As you can probably tell: I'm not an expert at website coding etc and just want this to work so I can do some basic scrapes. Any thoughts on what's going on? Please suggest more info to add if I've missed anything valuable out. Apologies this isn't a true MWE but the GitHub repository does work (provided you go get a free API Scraper key).

**Update with more details of issue**

The key line seems to be the for res in ... loop - specifically the response.xpath bit. Printing the quantity 'response.xpath('//*[@data-rp]')' returns the following on successful extractions of a page of results (in square brackets):

[image: response.xpath upon successful processing of next scholar page]

But returns just an empty pair of square brackets when the run breaks down and quits. I'm very ignorant of what precisely this step is doing but this is definitely where the issue arises. Are there alternatives to this response.xpath() code that might not fail? Or is it accurately reflecting the fact that for some reason the next page (which definitely exists given how the programme sometimes scrapes 20+ and sometimes only 2 pages for the same search) isn't being found?

Comment: It seems to stop gracefully. Are you sure there are any other pages to follow? Double check if there are any `next_page`s to follow.

Comment: Looking at https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=airbnb gives 100 pages of results (so in terms of the urls the programme scans you go up to https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=990&q=airbnb&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5 - where the start=990 is the key bit); my 'runs' don't get that far (and sometimes capture more sometimes fewer articles).

Comment: The fact is that spider doesn't encounter error - only 2XX status codes, 15 enqueued - 15 dequeued. It could be that selector is broken, or the data is downloaded in a async way and rendered later on the page. Add some logging regarding `next_page`, if possible try to even save that page in a file. The webpage that you see in browser easily could be different from what Scrapy sees - as it doesn't render the page.

Comment: @SerhiiShynkarenko - the issue seems to arise in that for res in ... loop. I've edited the answer above to show what is printed in successful and unsuccessful loops. What really perplexes me is the randomness - I just ran the spider twice: first time went through 23 pages and the second time it went through just two before stopping.

Comment: Maybe you don't even need to scrape part with "next" button. Google shows like 10 events in page (=pagination) and the url looks like "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=170&q=airbnb", with 170 events I guess skipped (=offset). So just schedule the request with url "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=XXX&q=airbnb", scrape events and if you managed to find any - schedule the next request "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start={XXX + 10}&q=airbnb". It could be easily bot protection, that prevents from getting the next page - you never know until you save the parsed page.

Comment: @SerhiiShynkarenko The exact result of printing the url at the bottom on a failed loop (removing my API key) is (sorry I can't make this visible in the comment - hopefully you can copy paste to see what it looks like):
http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=XXX&url=https%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.com%2Fscholar%3Fstart%3D100%26q%3Dairbnb%26hl%3Den%26as_sdt%3D0%2C5&country_code=us

Comment: For the record, when you strip off the api stuff at the beginning of that url and convert the various %3d (an equals sign I've learned) stuff etc you get the following url which does take you to the page you'd expect of airbnb google Scholar results: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=100&q=airbnb&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&country_code=us

Comment: Just noticed - your [`allowed_domains`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains) seems to be incorrect. Try removing it.

Comment: Thanks @SerhiiShynkarenko - that seems to have helped but it's still a little random after commenting out that line. But getting over 200 now, e.g. returned 250 items one time then 260 the next. Perhaps this can more easily be explained by some of the other issues you noted above. What does the allowed domains thing do? Should it be set to anything?

Comment: This filters out urls, whose domains are not in the list. E.g., if you have `allowed_domains = ['www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com']`, then the request `Request(url='www.apple.com', ...)` will be ignored by Scrapy